# Low resolution Dektop intel i7 3770 and intel board DH67BL

Tags: display, resolution

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 in a desktop with the following specs:

```
 CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz 
 Motherboard: Intel DH67B
```

However the monitor is not identified (Monitor: Unknown) such that maximum resolution is 1024x768. This occurs with Samsung Syncmaster 2033 (resolution 1900x600), and is the same with ViewSonic VX2453mh-LED (resolution 1920x1080). I'd be very grateful if anyone could give me a suggestion as to how to fix the resolution.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the matter but telling users what graphics card you're using might help as it could be an issue related to your graphics card driver.

Comment: Thank you. The card driver is intel too, integrated to the motherboard intel DH67BL.